# File Upload and display in a single click

Tags: asp.net, css, file-upload

I want to upload a file and display the contents  of that file in a `grid` using a `FileUpload` and a `button` control .But i need to do both the events in a single button click .I tried to Hide the `FileUpload` control but this doesn't work that well.

Following are the css style definitions i tried to apply :

```
     <div style="height: 89px; width: 620px; position: relative; top: 226px; left: 229px; overflow:hidden">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"
        Style=" top:1px; left:-10px; width: 265px; position: relative; height: 26px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0)"
        Font-Size="30pt" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Choose file.."
        Style="top: -5px; left:-265px; z-index: -1; width: 251px; position: relative;"
        Height="22px" />
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to serve my purpose.

Is there any way that will allow me to `browse the file and display it in single button click`?

Comment: didint got what u meant..do u want to show file browser in single click and auto select any file and close?

Comment: i have to select a file first which i do with Fileupload control and then i need to save the uploaded file to a gridview which i do with a button click. Can i confine these two events to just one click of a button , instead of two clicks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will help

```
uploadButton.Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:hidden");
inputFile.Attributes.Add("onchange", "var uploadControl = document.getElementById('" + uploadButton.ClientID + "'); uploadControl.click();");
```